# How to retrieve multiple select values from sessionStorage and put them into the original form field

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

I want to store values from a form input field that has a tags input functionality using select multiple and automatically retrieve them back after the form was sent. Basically, what I am trying to achieve is to just keep them in the input field after form submission. With them being tags, this adds convenience to the user since you can just add/delete some of the inputs and reload the page.

I have successfully written a piece of code that stores the array in sessionStorage after clicking the submit button, where `pmids[]`is the id of the select element:

```
function store() {
  var select = document.getElementById('pmids[]');
  var pmids = [...select.options]
                  .filter(option => option.selected)
                  .map(option => option.value);
  sessionStorage.setItem("pmids", JSON.stringify(pmids));
}
```

I am struggling with getting the values back into the form field though, this attempt does not seem to work:

```
var storedPmids = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("pmids"));
if (storedPmids !== null) {
  document.getElementById("pmids[]" options).each(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < storedPmids.length; i++) {
        if (this.value == storedPmids[i]) {
        this.selected = true;
        }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of this line:

```
document.getElementById("pmids[]" options)
```

This is not how you access the options of a `<select>` element. Instead you should call:

```
document.getElementById("pmids[]").options
```

Furthermore, `each` is a jQuery method. The vanilla JS equivalent of `each` is `forEach`, which, in fact, only works with arrays and nodelists. Hence you need to convert your options collection into an array first:

```
var options = Array.from(document.getElementById("pmids[]").options);
```

Finally, `this` inside `forEach` refers to the window object, so you need to use a callback function with a parameter. Full code:

```
var storedPmids = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("pmids"));
if (storedPmids !== null) {
  var options = Array.from(document.getElementById("pmids[]").options);
  options.forEach(function(option) {
    for (var i = 0; i < storedPmids.length; i++) {
      if (option.value == storedPmids[i]) {
        option.selected = true;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. however, i am unfortunately still not getting the values back into the form field. should i not create the options variable from the stored values as opposed to the form field (which would have been emptied on form submit?). in any case, I tried and it didn't change the outcome, sadly

Comment: I just noticed, I think pretty crucial info to have is that the form field in question is empty in the beginning, i.e., there is no list of predefined options to choose from like with a classic dropdown. Rather, the items are generated after the user enters something and presses return, when the entered value is then transformed into a tag. As such, there is no "base" option list to map against. Sorry, should have specified this earlier.

Comment: In this case you would first create the options then run this code.